# How to number equations inside an 'aligned' environment, and how to cross-reference them using '\cref'?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, cleveref, aligned

**An illustration of the issue by way of a minimal working example**

I saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
a + b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{multline*}
\begin{aligned}
\forall B\in\mathcal{P}\mathbb{Z}\forall a\in\mathbb{Z}\forall v\in\mathbb{N}_1\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_1&\bullet\\
\Big(\forall d\in D^n\exists w\in\mathbb{Z}^n&\bullet\\
&\phantom{\wedge}\enspace|w|\in P[v\,..\,v+n)\,\\
&\wedge\enspace\big(\forall k\in[1\,..\,n]\bullet d_k(a+\sum_{i=1}^kw_i)>0\big)\,\\
&\wedge\enspace a+\sum w\in B\Big)
\end{aligned}\\
\implies\forall C\in R_{a,v}[D^n]\bullet C\cap B\neq\emptyset
\end{multline*}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:last}
x + y = z
\end{equation}

References: \eqref{eq:first}, \crefrange{eq:first}{eq:last}
\end{document}
```

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
> lualatex Test
```

As a result, the file `~/Test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows.

[image: The output of the actual code]

**Question**

I'd like to number the three lines whose code includes the command `\wedge`, using the same counter as the one used to number the external equations. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to label these equations, and refer to them via both `\eqref` as well as the `cleveref` package. How can I do this?

**Remarks**

1. The reason I used an `aligned` environment inside a `multline` environment was so that the last line of this environment would overlap the previous three lines. Therefore, solutions that use the `alignat` environment to position the last line in a separate column to the right of the previous lines would not be considered suitable.
2. Mico's answer below, which I have accepted, makes use of the `\mathrlap` command from the `mathtools` package. [Here](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf) is an excellent read about this and related commands. I found a reference to this article in the `mathtools` manual.

Comment: Environment `aligned` is designed for write unnumbered equation. Use `align` instead od it.

Comment: Also, in `align` (non-starred), you can suppress numbering if you append `\notag`.

Comment: @Zarko Impossible, since the `align` environment can't be nested.

Comment: Why you should nested? A way, how ca be this done with it (or with `alignat` ) was shown in nice @Mico answer, but you refuse it (even down wote?!). So, I not see any way to help you.

Comment: @Zarko As my remark shows, the structure of the actual display I'm interested in does not break down neatly into columns. You can see that the first five lines can be put in columns (hence the nested `aligned` environment), but the last line overlaps the previous three lines. Mico's answer was no good. It worked on the MWE, sure, but was useless in addressing my actual needs as shown in the remark. His downvote was deserved. On the contrary, the downvotes I've been getting are spiteful. I was originally given an upvote.

Comment: Sorry, your approach is wrong and cannot work as you expected.

Comment: @Zarko It would be helpful if you indicate in what way my approach is wrong.

Comment: You refuse a (only) possible way.  See my answer below, which repat @Mico answer with some fine tuning and from image partly rewritten your real content. To help you, according to your reputation, you should know that here is desired to provide an MWE and not only code fragment ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you employ a single `alignat` environment for the five equations in question. Then, use `\notag` instructions for the equations which should *not* be numbered, and `\label` instructions for the equations which should be numbered.

(Addendum: The following LaTeX code and hence the associated screenshot as well are based on the subsequently-deleted initial code snippet provided by the OP.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{alignat}{3}
  A&                   \notag        \\
  B&                   \notag        \\
   &&\hspace{1cm}
      &\mathrlap{C}    \label{eq:a3} \\
   && &\mathrlap{D}    \label{eq:a4} \\
   && &&\hspace{5cm}
         &F            \notag
\end{alignat}
\lipsum[1][3-4]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:last}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
References: \labelcref{eq:first}, 
            \cref{eq:a3,eq:a4}, 
            \crefrange{eq:first}{eq:last}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: After I posted the answer shown above, the OP deleted the initial code snippet and posted some real code. Applying the `alignat` suggestion to the OP's update equations, one gets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathrlap macro
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for \mathbb macro
\usepackage{cleveref}  % for \cref, \crefrange, and \labelcref macros
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
a + b = c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{alignat}{3}
\forall B\in\mathcal{P}\mathbb{Z},
\forall a\in\mathbb{Z},
\forall v\in\mathbb{N}_1,
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_1 
 && \bullet \notag\\
\Bigl(\forall d\in D^n\exists w\in\mathbb{Z}^n
 && \bullet \notag\\
 && \mathrlap{\phantom{\wedge}\enspace|w|\in P[v\,..\,v+n)} 
    \label{eq:aaa} \\[\jot]
 && \mathrlap{\wedge\enspace\bigl(\forall k\in[1\,..\,n]
              \bullet d_k
              \bigl(a+\smash{\sum_{i=1}^k} w_i\bigr)>0\bigr)}
    \label{eq:bbb} \\
 && \mathrlap{\wedge\enspace a+\sum w\in B\Bigr)} 
    \label{eq:ccc} \\[2ex]
 &&&\hspace{1.5cm}
    & \implies\forall C\in R_{a,v}[D^n]\bullet 
      C\cap B\neq\emptyset \notag
\end{alignat}
\lipsum[1][4-6]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:last}
x + y = z
\end{equation}
References: \labelcref{eq:first}, 
            \crefrange{eq:first}{eq:last},
            \cref{eq:aaa,eq:ccc}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is not good for me. The environments cannot be changed to `alignedat`.

Comment: +1, not sure what is going on here :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - I decided to undelete and expand the answer purely to demonstrate to the OP that his derisive dismissal of the `aligned` approach -- "Mico's answer was no good. It ... was useless in addressing my actual needs as shown in the remark. His downvote was deserved" -- was, in fact, not at all warranted. I'm not going to hold my breath to see if he changes his mind, though.

Comment: I wish I would have your patience and maturity :) (going offline now, the day begins!).

Comment: "dismissal" - true. "derisive" - not true. And my dismissal was misjudged. If you'd explained the purpose of the `\mathrlap` commands, I would probably have accepted your original answer.

Comment: Thank you very much to reopen the answer. Now I can upvote it ...

Comment: What a good start of New Year :)

Comment: @EvanAad - Your initial (and subsequently deleted) code snippets mentioned nothing about a potential horizontal overlap among the groups of rows. I included the `\mathrlap` directives anyway because I had an *inkling* -- but no firm evidence -- that alllowing for such an overlap might be needed/desirable. Had you provided the real equations right away, instead of `A`, `B`, etc., I would have definitely explained the purpose of the `\mathrlap` directives in suitable detail up front.

Answer (score 7):

Since OP refuse nice @Mico answer, I not expect that with mine, which is based on it,  will happens any different. So, its intention is to show anyone else with similar problem the possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dumm text filler

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    \forall C\in\mathcal{P}\mathbb{Z}  \ \forall a\in\mathbb{Z}\ 
    &
    \forall a\in\mathcal{P}\mathbb{N}_1\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}_1 \cdot
         &              \\
    & \Bigl(\forall d \in\mathcal{D}^n\ \exists w\mathbb{Z}^n\cdot
         &              \\
    &   \wedge\enspace\enspace|w|\in P[v\,..\,v+n)\,\\
    &   \wedge\enspace\big(\forall k\in[1\,..\,n]\bullet d_k(a+\sum_{i=1}^kw_i)>0\big)\,\\
&\wedge\enspace a+\sum w\in B\Bigr)
                &        \\
    &\hspace{9em}  \implies\forall C\in R_{a,v}[D^n]\bullet C\cap B\neq\emptyset
                &
    \end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:last}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
References: \eqref{eq:first}, \crefrange{eq:first}{eq:last} \dots
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Now my MWE  (partly) consider MWE provided in the edited question. BTW, my observation
shows that result from my MWE is quite similar to image shown in OP question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a suitable solution, because line (6) should overlap with line (5). This is the reason I used an `aligned` environment inside a `multline` environment. I have now added to my answer the code used to produce the screenshot seen in my remark.

Comment: @EvanAad, as I said in answer, my answer is not intended for you. Now I edit it and consider provided code for equations.

Comment: @Mico. I saw your answer when it was already closed. So I wasn't able to upvote it, as it deserve.

Comment: +1, not sure what is going on here :) (same as Mico's answer).